# Bash insert saved file name to variable

Tags: bash

The below script download file using CURL, I'm trying inside the loop to save the file and also to insert the saved file name into a variable and then to print it.

My script downloads the script and saved the file but can't echo the saved file name:

```
for link in $url2; do
    cd /var/script/twitter/html_files/ && file1=$({ curl -O $link ; cd -; })
    echo $file1
done
```

Script explanation:

$url2 contains one or more URLs

curl -O write output to a file named as the remote file

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several problems.  Assuming `$url2` is a list of valid URLs which do not require shell quoting, you can make `curl` print the output variable directly.

```
cd /var/script/twitter/html_files
for link in $url2; do
    curl -s -w '%{filename_effective}\n' -O "$link"
done
```

Without the `-w` *formatstring* option, the output of `curl` does not normally contain the output file name in a conveniently machine-readable format (or actually at all).  I also added an `-s` option to disable the download status output it prints by default.

There is no point in doing `cd` to the same directory over and over again inside the loop, or capturing the output into a variable which you only use once to print to standard output the string which `curl` by itself would otherwise print to standard output.

Finally, the `cd -` does not seem to do anything useful here; even if it did something useful *per se,* you are doing it in a subshell, which doesn't change the current working directory of the script which contains the `$(cd -)` command substitution.

If your task is to temporarily switch to that directory, then switch back to where you started, just `cd` once.  You can use `cd -` in Bash but a slightly more robust and portable solution is to run the fetch in a subshell.

```
( cd directory;
  do things ...
)
# you are now back to where you were before the cd
```

If you genuinely need the variable, you can trivially use

```
for link in $url2; do
    file1=$(curl -s -w '%{filename_effective}' -O "$link")
    echo "$file1"
done
```

but obviously the variable will only contain the result from the last iteration after the loop (in the code after `done`).  (The format string doesn't need the final `\n` here because the command substitution will trim off any trailing newline anyway.)

Comment: Anyway, I need the output within a variable. I'm going to use it for more things inside the loop. How can I do this?

Comment: @bugnet `variable=$(command)` sets `variable` to the standard output of `command`